# Getting trouble explicit proxy

Tags: proxy.pac, wpad.dat

I'm using google geocoder in my PHP application.
It's working fine, but the issue is:

Recently network changes were done in office.
Now we are using explicit proxy (`wpad.dat`) in place of transparent proxy and in the Firewall the `allow any to any` access rule is removed.

After this change google geocoder is not working well and the browser shows "irresponsive page".
Even the SVN server also taking lot of time for checking after the proxy changes.

I've added `if (shExpMatch(url, "*.maps.google.com/*")) return "DIRECT";` in `wpad.dat` file but it didn't help.

Whenever I'm placing the `allow any to any` ACL in the firewall,
then everything is working fine.
However, as of security measures we are not going to add this rule in the firewall again.

How to overcome this issue ?

Comment: did you solve this already. I have the same problem